# gettext problem with validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gettext

I have a validation message

```
self.errors.add_to_base(_("country cannot be deleted #{self.country_name}"))
```

this is not working.

But simple messages like

```
self.errors.add_to_base(_("country cannot be deleted"))
```

working fine.

I am converting this messages to spanish.

Any idea or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use a parameter in the call to gettext and then interpolate that with the value you want to pass in. E.g.

```
self.errors.add_to_base(_("country cannot be deleted %{country}") % { :country => self.country_name})
```

More information [here](http://www.yotabanana.com/hiki/ruby-gettext-howto-rails.html).